# Getting page indexed after fixing rel canonical error

Tags: seo, google, rel

I found a WordPress plugin created a `rel="canonical"` error in a section of my site.  This error caused lower pages to point to the main page via a `rel="canonical"`.  I fixed the error 3 weeks ago and removed `rel="canonical"` from my site.

However, Google will not seem to index the lower pages that had the `rel="canonical"`error.

Am I just doomed with getting these lower pages indexed now that my `rel="canonical"` error originally told Google these pages were duplicates of the main page?

I even submitted that whole section of the site to be recrawled in Webmaster Tools but Google will not index the lower pages.

Anyone have any other tips I should follow?

Answer (score 1):

It might just be a matter of time until Google crawls and indexes them without [rel="canonical"](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139394?hl=en), but the following might help:

- Use the [Fetch as Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/158587?hl=en) tool to trigger crawling for the updated URLs (follow the steps there).
- In your [sitemap](http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html), indicate the last modification date by supplying the [lastmod](http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html) attribute.
- Also in your sitemap, specify the [priority](http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html) attribute for the updated URLs as a high number (e.g., `1.0`).
- Finally [resubmit your sitemap to Google Webmaster Tools](https://support.google.com/sites/answer/100283?hl=en).

Then periodically check for the URLs using `site:mydomain.com/url` (it can take up to weeks).